# On click function into on load function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code

```
$(function() {
    // run the currently selected effect
    function runEffect() {
        // get effect type from
        var selectedEffect = $( "#effectTypes" ).val();

        // most effect types need no options passed by default
        var options = {};
        // some effects have required parameters
        if ( selectedEffect === "scale" ) {
            options = { percent: 100 };
        } else if ( selectedEffect === "size" ) {
            options = { to: { width: 280, height: 185 } };
        }

        // run the effect
        $( "#effect" ).show( selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
    };

    //callback function to bring a hidden box back
    function callback() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $( "#effect:visible" ).removeAttr( "style" ).fadeOut();
        }, 1000 );
    };

    // set effect from select menu value
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
        runEffect();
    });
```

like dis i want to change dis on click function into on load function am a beginner so please help me

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly you want to run the runEffect function on page load?

You can do this by calling the function from within the jQuery ready event.

```
// This is shorthand for $(document).ready(function() { ... })
$(function() {
    // Declare the runEffect function here

    runEffect();
});
```